# How can i resolve HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443) Max retries exceeded with url (Google cloud storage)

Tags: google-api, python-requests, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created API using Django Rest Framework.
API communicates with GCP cloud storage to store profile Image(around 1MB/pic).
While performing load testing (around 1000 request/s) to that server.
I have encountered the following error.
I seem to be a GCP cloud storage max request issue, but unable to figure out the solution of it.

```
Exception Type: SSLError at /api/v1/users

Exception Value: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /storage/v1/b/<gcp-bucket-name>?projection=noAcl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))
```

Comment: Does it upload any of the pictures? Or directly it gives you the error right when throw the API request? Also what is the API request you are sending?

Comment: yeah, it serves around 995 requests, but for 5 this error was thrown. basically, I'm trying to make 1000s of connection with GCP bucket (GCP-bucket-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have the answer to your question [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#auto-scaling):

- "...buckets have an initial IO capacity of around 1000 write requests
  per second...As the request rate for a given bucket grows, Cloud
  Storage automatically increases the IO capacity for that bucket"

Therefore it automatically Auto-Scale. The only thing is that you need to increase the requests/s gradually as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#ramp-up):

- "If your request rate is expected to go over these thresholds, you should start with a request rate below or near the thresholds and then double the request rate no faster than every 20 minutes"

Looks like your bucket should get an increase of I/O capacity that will work in the future.

You are actually right in the edge (1000 req/s), but I guess this is what is causing your error.

Comment: Apart from limiting the load on storage, how to handle this error in case of a sudden spike. This error do not give any error code as well.