# Error while trying to connect to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I'm using service account in order to connect my Kubernetes pod (which is actually neo4j backup pod which uses service account secret) to Google Cloud Storage. I've attached **admin** role (of course when the issue will be solved I will fine-grain this access) to this service account just to be sure that it is not policy issue. I'm getting error though.

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TransportError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1ee4afca90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

What is the reason of that and how can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i resolve HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443) Max retries exceeded with url (Google cloud storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274552/how-can-i-resolve-httpsconnectionpoolhost-www-googleapis-com-port-443-max-r)

Comment: Do you have pubic IPs on the nodes?

Comment: @DazWilkin No really, I'm trying to send backup for the first time so I guess I'm am far from having 1000 write requests per second.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, there is external IPs on every node. How this is connected to the issue?

Comment: If the nodes didn't have public IPs they wouldn't be able to connect (receive traffic from the) service. It was a reasonable question.

Comment: Please add the (Deployment|Pod) spec to your question.

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes, it was reasonable question. So there is no private connection between GKE nodes and GCS?

Comment: There are various ways to configure Kubernetes Pods to communicate with GCP services. There's a new way (that I've not used) and there's an old way of creating a Kubernetes service account that wraps a GCP service account. Let me dig up links for you.

Comment: The new (recommended) way: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity I need to try this approach out as I'm stuck in the old way of creating Kubernetes service accounts that wrap GCP service accounts.

Comment: This all said, I'm surprised you don't get a 403.

Comment: Yes, @DazWilkin you are right and this was also a cause of my issue. So it appears that I started to configure it with Workload Identity and have not finished it but docs say: Modify an existing node pool to enable GKE_METADATA. This update succeeds only if Workload Identity is enabled on the cluster. It immediately enables Workload Identity for workloads deployed to the node pool. This change will prevent workloads from using the Compute Engine service account and must be carefully rolled out. So when using workload identity we cannot use service account anymore - that is how I get error.

Comment: @Murakami if you already found a solution. Can you please post it as an answer for visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As requested I'm answering my own question*

It appears that I started to configure my workloads with Workload Identity. Then for some reason I wanted to come back to service account authentication type. But the node pool was already modified to work with Workload Identity. That is why I could not use service account anymore.
I missed that part of Google documentation:

> This change will prevent workloads from using the Compute Engine
> service account and must be carefully rolled out. So when using
> workload identity we cannot use service account anymore.