# Upload large csv file to cloud storage using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-cloud-platform

Hi I am trying to upload a large csv file but I am getting the below error:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /upload/storage/v1/b/de-bucket-my-stg/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ADPycdsyu6gSlyfklixvDgL7RLpAQAg6REm9j1ICarKvmdif3tASOl9MaqjQIZ5dHWpTeWqs2HCsL4hoqfrtVQAH1WpfYrp4sFRn (Caused by SSLError(SSLWantWriteError(3, 'The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2396)')))

Can someone help me on this?

Below is my code for it:

```
   import os
    import pandas as pd
    import io
    import requests
    from google.cloud import storage
    
    try:
        url = "https://cb-test-dataset.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/analytics/analytics.csv"
        cont = requests.get(url).content
        file_to_upload = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(cont.decode('utf-8')))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error getting file: ' +  str(e))
    
    try:
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'C:/Users/haris/Desktop/de-project/xxx.json' --xxx is replaced here.
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket_name = storage_client.get_bucket('de-bucket-my-stg')
        blob = bucket_name.blob('analytics.csv')
        blob.upload_from_string(file_to_upload.to_csv(),'text/csv')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error uploading file: ' +  str(e))
```

Comment: Are you able to write any small file on the same location ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi yes i uploaded a sample test csv. Which was successfull

Comment: Then it may be the case your internet connection is not stable.

Comment: Yes, my internet connection is slow though. Do you find any other problem here?

Comment: If there is a problem then you will not be able to upload small files either so in my opinion its just the internet issue

Comment: Try to run you script from Cloud Shell or from a VM.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62307667/15774176),

> My recommendation is to gzip your file before sending it. Text file
> has an high compression rate (up to 100 times) and you can  [ingest
> gzip files directly into BigQuery without unzipped them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data)
>
> The fastest method of uploading to Cloud Storage is to use the
> [compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose) API and composite objects.

For more information, you can refer to the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305134/15774176) where OP is facing a similar error.

Comment: @Zuffido Posted an answer, is it helpful?